# preposition to describe a place across from and next to

Tags: prepositions

I am aware the meaning of "**across from**".

For instance, in the image below, **across from** the library
are the post office and the grocery, the gas station is **across from**
the park.

[image]

I am wondering if there is a preposition phrase could be used to describe the gas station in reference to the library in the image above.

Could someone please give a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diagonally across from, or "catty-corner" from. (The second term has several alternate spellings.)

American Heritage dictionary
[diagonal](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=diagonal)
[catty-corner](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=catty-corner)

Comment: 'Catty-corner' or 'kitty-corner' are distinctly American terms that a British English zone speaker would probably not immediately understand. They would, however understand 'diagonally opposite to' or 'diagonally across from' somewhere.